# Group By and summaries with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data frame `df`. After `group_by(id, Year, Month, new_used_ind)` and `summarise(n = n())` it looks like:

```
id  Year   Month  new_used_ind   n
1   2001   apr     N             3
1   2001   apr     U             2
2   2002   mar     N             5
3   2003   mar     U             3
4   2004   july    N             4          
4   2004   july    U             2
```

I want to add and get total for id, year and month but also want a total of ' N' from new_used_ind in a new column.

Something like this

```
id  Year   Month  Total_New   total
1   2001   apr     3            5
2   2002   mar     5            8
4   2004   july    4            6
```

Comment: You wanna group by id or year or month? your desired output shows grouping only by month!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)

read.table(text= "id  Year   Month  new_used_ind   n
1   2001   apr     N             3
1   2001   apr     U             2
2   2002   mar     N             5
3   2003   mar     U             3
4   2004   july    N             4          
4   2004   july    U             2", header = T) -> df

df %>%
  group_by(id, Year, Month) %>%
  mutate(total_New=sum(n*(new_used_ind=="N"))) %>% 
  mutate(total_n=sum(n)) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("total_New", "total_n"), mean)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   id, Year [4]
#>      id  Year Month total_New total_n
#>   <int> <int> <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1  2001 apr           3       5
#> 2     2  2002 mar           5       5
#> 3     3  2003 mar           0       3
#> 4     4  2004 july          4       6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Does the 2 and 3 rows needs to be summed i.e. grouped by 'Month', get the first of 'id', 'Year' and sum the total_New and 'total_n'

Comment: @akrun well I asked OP what variables the wanna group by. In the text they said group by year, id, and month but desired output is based on month only.